# Can a DIV tag be set so as not to push the objects below down?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the problem in pictures:

[image]

The `Modify` button is about to be clicked, and voila:

[image]

Clicking on `Modify` causes the rest of the objects below to move down:

Is there a feature to make the drop-down box to `FLOAT` over the objects below?

And here is all the code pertinent to this case...

First the `HTML` portion:

```
<body>
<div id="zMenu" class="relDiv" style="position:relative; width:800px; top:34px;">
    <ul id="navlist" style="position:relative; height:30px; display:block;">
        <li id="leader"></li>  
        <li id="home" ><a href="javascript:showImportWin()"><span style="position:relative; left:0px; top:7px;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Import</span></a></li>
        <li id="home2"><a href="javascript:showExportWin()"><span style="position:relative; left:6px; top:7px;">Export</span></a></li>
        <li id="home3"><a href="http://clients.jic.com/reports" ><span style="position:relative; left:5px; top:7px;">Proxy Reports</span></a></li>
        <li id="home4"><a href="javascript:helpScreen()"><span style="position:relative; left:6px; top:7px;">Help</span></a></li>
        <li id="home5"><a href="javascript:showModify()"><span style="position:relative; left:3px; top:7px;">Modify</span></a></li>
        <li id="home6"><a href="http://clients.jic.com/reports/logout"><span style="position:relative; left:5px; top:7px;">Logout</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="modify" >
        <div class="listmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="JavaScript:hideModify('Settings')">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="JavaScript:hideModify('Funds')">Funds</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="JavaScript:hideModify('Listings')">Listings</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="JavaScript:hideModify('Report')">Report Details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now, the CSS portion:

```css
#modify {
    position: inherit;
    top:-30px;
    z-index:1050;
    /*background-image: url(../static/SearchHeader3.png);*/
    left:515px;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    width: 120px;
    background-color :#fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;

}

.listmenu ul {
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    padding: 0 0 2px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:120px;
    text-align: left;
}

.listmenu li a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    border-left:3px solid #fff;
    border-right:3px solid #fff;
    /*height: 16px;*/
    padding: 4px 0 4px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.listmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #fec;
    color:#a2a;
}
```

Many thanks for your help,

DK

Comment: Absolute and relative positioning is what you're looking for.

Comment: Check out absolute positioning.

Comment: @j08691  I cannot use absolute because this is an application and it needs to be centered at all times.  Some people use it in full screen mode others unpin the browser and use it in reduced size.  An app sitting on the left side of the screen looks rather dubious.

Comment: Also look at `z-index`.

Comment: @Andrew Peacock  z-index controls which div is visible, not the positioning.

Comment: @DKean Posted before I saw he couldn't use `absolute`. When `z-index` and `absolute` are used together, it would pop the element over the others.

Comment: @DKean - z-index controls exactly what it sounds like - the Z index. It doesn't have anything to do with visibility... unless you mean you use it in your code to drop things below a certain visible element point

Comment: Absolute positioning on your menu won't blow out the positioning of your whole layout.

Comment: @DKean If you use absolute positioning, you can always center it on your screen.  You would just say `left:50%;` and then `margin-left:-200px;`  (the 200px will be whatever it needs to be to set the thing in the right spot.).  This way it will always be centered on the screen

Comment: The fact that you want it centered has nothing to do with absolute positioning. With absolute positioning, you have complete control over where it gets positioned. For example, in your case it should be directly below the modify nav button. So, using javascript, get the position of that button then position the popup centered directly below it on click/hover etc.

Comment: @KaiQing Yes, you are right.  And I must apologize to all, because it seems that `position:absolute` without coordinates does not commandeer the div!  I would never have guessed that.  Thank you all again!

Comment: @KevinB It would seem that you are right.  The `relative` and `absolute` directives confuse me still.  Thank you for the kindness of explaining it.

Comment: @ntgCleaner  Brilliant solution.  I did not think of that.  Thank you for expanding my understanding on this.  I'm still learning to use what I already know, but it takes a problem like this to get me to rethink it. Brilliant...

Comment: @j08691 I have had problems with absolute positioning in the past so I seem to have overreacted to its extent of influence over the objects.  Time to go back to w3schools.com to get it straight once and for all.  Thank you for the explanation.  Very kind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute`

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <div id="modify" >
     ...
    </div>
</div>
or 

<div id="modify" style="position: absolute;">
 ...
</div>
```

And you need use `z-index`.

Comment: your answer seems to work, though I have an arbitration between the z-indexes of the competing objects.  But I think that I can resolve that!  Thank you very much @Mahmut.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `position:absolute` on `.listmenu`.

Comment: On the listmenu it does not work.  However @Mahmut 's suggestion seems to work ...